# Find the limiting value of a Delayed (or Ordinary) Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, reference-request, integro-differential-equations

## General Question

Suppose we have a function $f(s)$ which satisfies an Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) $f'(s) = A(s,f(s))$ which can not be solved explicitly. Is there some method to find $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} f(s)$? In particular I am interested in this question for Delayed Differential Equations (DDE). What I am looking for is some reference where such a method is outlined (I am also interested in this question with regard to Integro-Differential Equations).

## Example Problem

Let $f(s)$ satisfy the DDE:
\begin{align*}
f'(s)&=a(f(s)^2-1) & s \in [0,1)\\
f'(s)&=a(f(s)^2-f(s-1)^2) & s \geq 1,
\end{align*}
$f(0) = a$. I know from numerical studies that in fact for $a \in (0,1)$ $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}f(s)=0$ for this case. However I do not know of any mathematical method to come to this result.

Comment: Doesn't the answer depend on $a$?  Is seems like if $a>1$, the solution would increase without bound.

Comment: I added this to the question, $a \in (0,1)$ how do you know it increases without bound if $a > 1$?

Comment: If $a>1$, then the derivative would always be positive, no?

Comment: O yes, you are quite right!

Comment: ODE and DDE tend to be quite different in this respect: there are techniques for ODE that don't work (or are much harder) for DDE.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm mainly intereseted in DDEs/IDEs, I just added ODEs because they are the most familiar to most and I had hoped that the methods for ODEs also applied for DDEs/IDEs.

Comment: In the case of DDEs, the initial value problem is to find a solution that satisfies, firstly, the DDE on some interval of the form $[0, A)$ (say), and, secondly, equals some given function on $[-1,0]$.  In your second example, for any real $b$ the function constantly equal to $b$ is a solution, so if you take $b\ne0$, $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty}f(s)\ne0$.

Comment: But in order for the function to be constant, wouldn't you need $f' = 0$, which would imply that $f(0) = 1$ or $-1$?

Comment: $f'(s) = 0$ implies $f(s) = \pm f(s-1)$.

Comment: Without enforcing f to be constant for the second part of the problem, you can try to show that the limit is zero.  The solution to $f'(s) = -af(s)^2$ for $f(0)>0$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$.  So you can try to squeeze your problem between two other ODEs which are both bounded below by zero and decreasing.  This would be using the Squeeze Test to prove that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my earlier comment, a solution of the DDE
$$
f'(s) = a(f(s)^2 - f(s-1)^2) 
$$
need not converge to zero.  However, one can ask if a solution converges to a constant.  And indeed the answer is yes, at least for bounded solutions. Namely, in their 1984 paper [Solutions of x′(t)=f(x(t),x(t−L)) have limits when f is an order relation](https://doi.org/10.1016/0362-546X(79)90034-8), J. Kaplan, F. Sorg and J. Yorke proved that if a continuous function $g(x, y)$ that is locally Lipschitz wrt $x$ satisfies the conditions:

1. $g(x, y) > 0$ if and only if $g(y, x) < 0$,
2. $g(x, y) \ge 0$ and $g(y, z) \ge 0$ implies $g(x , z) \ge 0$,

then each **bounded** solution converges to a constant as $t \to \infty$.  Now, the function $g(x, y) = a (x^2 - y^2)$ satisfies the above conditions.

Comment: Very interesting reference! Do you know of any similar result which would help analyze $f'(s)=a(f(s)-f(s-1))f(s-1)$

Comment: There are results on the so-called pseudo-monotone flows, such as, for instance, [Haddock, Nkashama and Wu](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0396(92)90116-50), or [Yi and Huang](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2005.02.005), or else [Liu](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2016.09.0180).  I don't know if they will be of any help to you.